# uniq -cd but as percentage

Tags: bash, unix, uniq

I have a file containing these lines:

```
"RedfishVersion":"1.6.0"
"RedfishVersion":"1.6.0"
"RedfishVersion":"1.6.0"
"RedfishVersion":"1.6.0"
"RedfishVersion":"1.6.0"
"RedfishVersion":"1.6.0"
"RedfishVersion":"1.15.0"
"RedfishVersion":"1.15.0"
"RedfishVersion":"1.15.0"
"RedfishVersion":"1.15.0"
"RedfishVersion":"1.15.0"
"RedfishVersion":"1.15.0"
"RedfishVersion":"1.15.0"
```

I was wondering if is there a Unix way to get a histogram percentage of these lines based on how many times it's repeated. This is my attempt:

```
sort bmc-versions.txt | uniq -cd
    321 "RedfishVersion":"1.0.0"
     19 "RedfishVersion":"1.0.2"
```

I want output like this:

```
"1.0.0"  50%
"1.0.2"  40%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Sorted by percentage (highest first) using GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"; PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"} {a[$2]++} END{for (i in a) {print i "  " int(a[i] / NR * 100 + 0.5) "%"}}' test.txt
"1.15.0"  54 %
"1.6.0"  46 %
```

Nicer formatting:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = ":"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
}

{
    a[$2]++
}

END {
    for (i in a) {
        print i "  " int(a[i] / NR * 100 + 0.5) "%"
    }
}' test.txt
"1.15.0"  54 %
"1.6.0"  46 %
```

---

#### Sorted by percentage (highest first) using 'non-GNU' awk (e.g. posix awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} {a[$2]++} END{for (i=NR; i>=0; i--) {for (h in a) {if(a[h] == i) {print h, int(a[h] / NR * 100 + 0.5), "%"}}}}' test.txt
"1.15.0" 54 %
"1.6.0" 46 %
```

Nicer formatting:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = ":"
}

{
    a[$2]++
}

END {
    for (i = NR; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (h in a) {
            if (a[h] == i) {
                print h, int(a[h] / NR * 100 + 0.5), "%"
            }
        }
    }
}' test.txt
"1.15.0" 54 %
"1.6.0" 46 %
```

Comment: Is there a way to sort by percentage too? the highest first

Comment: Nice answer. `int(a[i] / NR * 100 + 0.5)` might be an option for a bit better rounding.

Comment: @Node.JS Here I've included a way to sort by percentage highest first. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76919139/12295334

Answer (score 1):

```
   awk -F'"' '{count[$4]++} END {for (version in count) {sum += count[version]} for (version in count) {printf "\"%s\" %.2f%%\n", version, (count[version] / sum) * 100}}' bmc-versions.txt | sort -k2,2nr
```

Here's what this command does:

- -F'"': Sets the field separator to a double quote, so we can easily extract the version number.
- {count[$4]++}: For each line, it increments the count for the
  corresponding version number.
- END {for (version in count) {sum += count[version]} for (version in
  count) {printf ""%s" %.2f%%\n", version, (count[version] / sum) *
  100}}: After processing all lines, this part calculates and prints
  the percentages for each version.
- sum += count[version]: Calculates the total count of lines. printf
  ""%s" %.2f%%\n", version, (count[version] / sum) * 100: Prints the
  version and its percentage.
- The sort -k2,2nr command sorts the lines based on the second column
  (the percentages) in descending numeric order.